# arcpy.GetParameterAsText Error 000539 and NameError

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

Trying to create a Python script tool to calculate fields that are persistent across some (not all) feature classes in several feature datasets. It worked fine with the variables for CNO and VID hardcoded, but now that I'm trying to use GetParameterAsText its throwing

`arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in NameError: name 'VID' is not defined`

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
CNO = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
VID = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if "CNMS_Dataset" in datasets:
    datasets.remove("CNMS_Dataset")
for ds in datasets:
    print(ds)
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        if 'CASE_NO' in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
            arcpy.management.CalculateField(in_table=fc, field="CASE_NO", expression='CNO', expression_type="PYTHON3")
        if 'VERSION_ID' in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
            arcpy.management.CalculateField(in_table=fc, field="VERSION_ID", expression='VID', expression_type="PYTHON3")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `VID` variable is only defined in your scripts scope, not in the `CalculateField` tool, you need to put the actual value into the expression.

So if CASE_NO and VID fields are numeric:

```
    if 'CASE_NO' in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
        arcpy.management.CalculateField(in_table=fc, field="CASE_NO", expression=CNO, expression_type="PYTHON3")
    if 'VERSION_ID' in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
        arcpy.management.CalculateField(in_table=fc, field="VERSION_ID", expression=VID, expression_type="PYTHON3")
```

Or if CASE_NO and VID fields are text, use f'{format}' strings:

```
    if 'CASE_NO' in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
        arcpy.management.CalculateField(in_table=fc, field="CASE_NO", expression=f'"{CNO}"', expression_type="PYTHON3")
    if 'VERSION_ID' in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
        arcpy.management.CalculateField(in_table=fc, field="VERSION_ID", expression=f'"{VID}"', expression_type="PYTHON3")
```